# How does Go unmarshall a string into a wrapped atomc int?

Tags: go, go-zap

Uber's logging library Zap has a `Config` struct, in which the log level is defined as follows:

```go
type Config struct {
    Level AtomicLevel `json:"level" yaml:"level"`
}
```

Where the type `AtomicLevel` is a `struct` that wraps Go's `atomic.Int32`:

```go
type AtomicLevel struct {
    l *atomic.Int32
}
```

With this setup, how can Go's `json.Unmarshall` successfully unmarshalls a `string`, say, "debug" into the correct atomic int value, as the following example illustrates?

```go
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"

    "go.uber.org/zap"
)

func main() {
    // For some users, the presets offered by the NewProduction, NewDevelopment,
    // and NewExample constructors won't be appropriate. For most of those
    // users, the bundled Config struct offers the right balance of flexibility
    // and convenience. (For more complex needs, see the AdvancedConfiguration
    // example.)
    //
    // See the documentation for Config and zapcore.EncoderConfig for all the
    // available options.
    rawJSON := []byte(`{
      "level": "debug",
      "encoding": "json",
    }`)

    var cfg zap.Config
    if err := json.Unmarshal(rawJSON, &cfg); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    logger, err := cfg.Build()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer logger.Sync()

    logger.Info("logger construction succeeded")
}
```

Comment: if `Unmarshall` not implemented, it use `UnmarshalText`, see this question for more information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46553730/whats-the-difference-between-unmarshaltext-and-unmarshaljson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AtomicLevel has an [UnmarshalText](https://pkg.go.dev/go.uber.org/zap#AtomicLevel.UnmarshalText) method, which means it implements the [encoding.TextUnmarshaler](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding#TextUnmarshaler) interface. When the JSON decoder sees a JSON string and the destination is a type that implements TextUnmarshaler, its UnmarshalText method is called to convert the string into an appropriate value (unless the type implements `json.Unmarshaler`, in which case that takes precedence. AtomicLevel doesn't.)